# How can we convert HTML string to Object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have an Html string like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <h1 class="greeting">Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

I need to convert this html string to Object in Javascript. i.e., I should get the same object result when used `.children()` method in jquery.I tried something like this:

```
a = '<div id="foo">
    <h1 class="greeting">Hello World!</h1>
</div>';
eval("{"+a+"}");
console.log(a);
```

But it didn't work. What method should I use in javascript to convert HTML string to Object notation. I should get each children node in object form. I do not want to use Jquery in this solution. I am expecting the exact output as shown in console

[image]

Comment: @A4L Your link does not have the answer what I expected. That page has irrelevant answers

Comment: That link __is__ the answer. You have an HTML string that you need converted to a DOM structure. You do not have JSON.

Comment: What do you want achieve?

Comment: I need HTML string to Object for further process

Comment: @A4L I am expecting the output as shown in question

Comment: @Anoop I am expecting the same output as shown in image

Comment: jQuery does not make the HTML element an object as you explained it.  No conversion takes place. jQuery creates a custom jQuery object with an array prototype and a custom constructor. It stores the matched element references as HTMLElement objects in it's array object (the same object type returned by getElementById and similar) . jQuery then adds a lot more custom properties to the jQuery object such as `selector, previousObjecty, etc..` In essence if you want to replicate jQuery you would do it similar to `var x = []; x.push(getElementById('foo'))` or similar.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl In Jquery, .children() method converts HTML elements to Object. I got the output in image only by using .children(). Now, I am  in a situation not to use Jquery.

Comment: @Ganesh: `$('..').children()` gives you a jQuery array with the children inside of it. Those children are still HTMLElements. They have not been converted. `$('..').children()[0]` returns the reference to the actual `HTMLElement` in the jQuery array, hence `$('..').children()[0] instanceof HTMLElement` results in `true`. Off course if you do `$('..').children().eq(0)` you get the jQuery wrapped version. You can simulate all that by simply creating your own array and pushing the `HTMLElement` references into it and add any custom helpers to it as well that keep returning you custom object.

Answer (score 3):

In image it is a jQuery object which you can create using following code

```
var a = '<div id="foo">\
    <h1 class="greeting">Hello World!</h1>\
</div>';
var aDom = jQuery(a);
console.log(aDom );
```

Pure JavaScript: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWDx6/)

```
var e = document.createElement("div");
e.id = "foo";
e.innerHTML = '<h1 class="greeting">Hello World!</h1>';

console.log(e);
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to achieve the same result using Javascript. I don't want to use any jquery library

Comment: @Ganesh but in image it is a jQuery object

Comment: I knew that. I need to get the same object using Javascript. What method should I use instead of .children() to achieve this result.

Comment: +1 Nice and simple. Here I though OP wanted an elaborate wrapper for all that like jQuery without using jQuery. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Edited

```
var a = '<div id="test"></div>';

var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');

htmlObject.innerHTML = a;

htmlObject.getElementById("test") = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this

```
<script>
var htmlStrObj = {};
htmlStrObj.container = '<div id="foo"><h1 class="greeting">Hello World!</h1></div>';
console.log(htmlStrObj);
</script>
```